# My custom Proxy for classes returns undefined when I get values from it

Tags: javascript, class, proxy

I'm trying to make a version of Proxy which supports classes. That includes instanceof which a normal Proxy doesn't support. Here is what I've got so far:

```js
let ClassProxy = function(TargetClass, args) { // A class which creates a Proxy of a class
 function extend(sup, base) {
  var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
   base.prototype, 'constructor'
  ); // Get the constructor
  base.prototype = Object.create(sup.prototype); // Create an object with the super's prototype and apply it to the base's prototype
  var handler = {
   construct: function(target, args) {
    var obj = Object.create(base.prototype);
    return this.apply(target, obj, args); // Call the constructor
   }, // Construct it
   apply: function(target, obj, args) {
    let obj1 = Reflect.construct(sup, args, function() {
     return obj
    }) // Construct
    let obj2 = Reflect.construct(base, args, function() {
     return obj
    })
    let proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)
    let obj1d = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj1))
    let obj2d = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj2))
    for (let k in obj1d) {
     let prop = obj1d[k]
     Object.defineProperty(proto, k, prop) // Attempt to apply the prototype from the super
    }
    for (let k in obj2d) {
     let prop = obj2d[k]
     Object.defineProperty(proto, k, prop) // Attempt to apply the prototype from the base
    }
    Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, proto)
    obj1d = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj1)
    obj2d = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj2)
    for (let k in obj1d) {
     let prop = obj1d[k]
     Object.defineProperty(obj, k, prop) // Attempt to set properties from the super
    }
    for (let k in obj2d) {
     let prop = obj2d[k]
     Object.defineProperty(obj, k, prop) // Attempt to set properties from the base
    }
    return obj
   } // The constructor of the ClassProxy
  }
  var proxy = new Proxy(base, handler); // Create a proxy which is a fake class to create fake classes
  descriptor.value = proxy; // Set the value for the constructor to the proxy above
  Object.defineProperty(base.prototype, 'constructor', descriptor); // Define the constructor
  return proxy;
 }
 let _Proxy = function() {
  return new Proxy(this, args) // Basically just lets me create a proxy with the custom arguments
 }
 _Proxy.prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(Proxy) // Apply the prototype of Proxy to _Proxy to allow the constructor to use .prototype
 return extend(TargetClass, _Proxy) // Combine the classes
}
ClassProxy.prototype.constructor = ClassProxy // Apply the constructor (calling and using new are the same)

let MyClass = class { // Original class
 constructor(myClassName) {
  console.log("Constructed MyClass! myClassName: "+myClassName) // Test (definitely works)
  this.name = myClassName
 }
}

let Haha = new ClassProxy(MyClass, { // A class proxy of the original class
 get(obj, key) { // A proxy argument
  console.log("Intercepted '"+key+"'!") // When I get "name" it should tell me (it doesn't)
  return Reflect.get(obj, key) // Return the real value
 }
})
let hahaInstance = new Haha("test") // The class proxy
console.log(hahaInstance.test) // Will put undefined and no "intercepted" message will happen
console.log(hahaInstance instanceof MyClass) // True
console.log(new Proxy(new MyClass("test2")) instanceof MyClass) // False (I want to get around this behavior)
```

It works properly and instanceof works but indexing the class returns undefined and the proxy methods aren't called. Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors work and you can still get the value that way. It seems to possibly be something to do with the Proxy class itself... Does anyone know if this is fixable?

Basically I want to make a custom version of Proxy which actually is an instance of a class but still acts like a Proxy.

EDIT:
Here was my original code:

```js
{
 // Creep is a class built into the game which is the entity that does all of the work for you
 let creepAPI = {
  moveTo: function() {
   // Optimized moveTo code (the original code can be slow in some rare cases and doesn't do exactly what I want)
  }
 }
 let _Creep = Creep
 Creep.constructor = function(creepId) { // Override the constructor
  return new Proxy(new _Creep(creepId), { // Make a proxy for the class
   get(real, index) { // Allows me to add custom API functions, etc.
    console.log("Index: "+index) // Output the index for testing
    if (creepAPI[index]) {
     return creepAPI[index]
    }
    return Reflect.get(real, index) // Get the index from the real creep
   }
  })
 }
 console.log(new Creep(otherCreep.id) instanceof _Creep) // otherCreep would be an actual instance of a creep (outputs false on my private server)
 
 // Now to use my api I just make a new creep from the id of the actual creep
}
```

Comment: Sorry, what? Why do you think a normal proxy does not support classes?

Comment: This is seriously convoluted code. I have no idea what you are doing there, nor what you are trying to do. Can you please give an example of the usage of this thing, and the expected output?

Comment: Sorry that it's confusing... If you proxy a class instanceof will be false no matter what. I'll edit my answer to show what I'm trying to do for you.

Comment: I updated it for you now... Sorry about that!

Comment: I still don't get what the actual problem is. `class Example {}; const x = new Proxy(new Example, {}); console.log(x instanceof Example)` works just fine and logs `true`.

Comment: interesting... I was testing this on a class in an API and it was returning false even though the original was returning true but if I make a new class myself it does work properly... Well thank you for trying to help... I'll have to figure out how to get around that weird bug unless the API gets updated.

Comment: Please post that code that does not work if you need help with it

Comment: I would if the VM/API was publicly accessible... I think I'm just going to have to figure it out on my own so sorry for being stupid lol.

Edit: I might as well post it anyway now that I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Bergi made me realize that a Proxy does support classes but the API I'm using has some sort of weird bug which I'm assuming is because of how the API works. It creates a completely isolated vm (I think it isn't even an actual node js VM) which is spawned from the main node js process and the global is passed to the VM somehow. I'm guessing it has to do with the way the global gets passed but I can't see how that works.

The real answer to this is Proxies actually do support classes and instanceof but within the VM instanceof and class extensions do not work exactly the same on built in API classes. I will have to figure out another way to do what I'm trying to do I assume.

If anyone is wondering what I'm talking about I'm trying to modify classes efficiently for my own code in a programming game called "Screeps" which is 15 USD on steam (so not accessible to people who don't have the game).

I apologize for my bad oversight.